# Recover a version controlled file from CVS

Tags: unix, version, cvs, rcs

My company has stopped using CVS. I have an archived file name.cpp,v.

How can I recover the latest name.cpp ?

NOTE : I dont have cvs repository in place now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install RCS (it's small, go for it) if you haven't already.

Then run `co name.cpp` in the same directory as `name.cpp,v`.

It should "check out" the latest version.